# Understanding the numbers in ggplot2 doc about boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html

> The upper whisker extends from the hinge to the largest value no further than 1.5 * IQR from the hinge (where IQR is the inter-quartile range, or distance between the first and third quartiles). The lower whisker extends from the hinge to the smallest value at most 1.5 * IQR of the hinge. Data beyond the end of the whiskers are called "outlying" points and are plotted individually.

> In a notched box plot, the notches extend 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n). This gives a roughly 95% confidence interval for comparing medians. See McGill et al. (1978) for more details.

The above text mentions 1.5 and 1.58. How are these numbers chosen as they are? What are they interpretation?

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Notched-box-plot-summary-An-example-of-a-notched-box-plot-with-labels-for-each_fig1_331235806

I am not sure what exactly *notched box plot* means. Is it something as mentioned in the above link?

I don't understand `the notches extend 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n)`. Which specific part of the boxplot it refers? Can anybody mark it explicitly on a boxplot to be clear?

I don't understand "This gives a roughly 95% confidence interval for comparing medians." Can anybody explain what it means (especially what is "comparing medians")?

I don't have access to `McGill et al. (1978)`. So I don't know what it says. If there is something already explained in the paper, please help summarize it here.

Answer (score 1):

There is general agreement about what the box and middle line in a box and whiskers plot (usually just called boxplot) represent. In contrast with respect to the whiskers there are multiple approaches described in the literature, as it is always tricky to decide which observations are outliers and which ones are not. `geom_boxplot()` uses `coef` * IQR as the criterion, with `coef = 1.5` as default. IQR refers to the interquartile range ("or distance"), in other words, the size of the box. IQR will depend on how variable the data are, and the relation between IQR and the range of the whole data set/group will depend on how long the tails of the distribution are. So 1.5 * IQR is a rather crude guess that does not take into consideration the number of observations, and is normally used for plotting the whiskers. While `geom_boxplot()` seems calls the parameter describing the multiplier `coef` in R's `boxplot()` it is called `range`, with `range = 1.5` as default. So in either case the user can change the value used. If we want the whiskers to represent the range of the observations, the value to use for `range` is zero, while in `stat_boxplot()` (or equivalently `geom_boxplot()`) one achieves this with `coef = Inf`.

If one assumes a given distribution, like the Normal, or uses the data themselves to estimate an empirical one, one can go further an infer a confidence interval for the median, which depends on the number of observations and a constant derived from the shape of the distribution. In this case `1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n)` is used as the approximation.

I was able to get access to the cited paper through https://www.jstor.org/stable/2683468. Quoting from it "The notches surrounding the medians provide a measure of the rough significance of differences between the values. Specifically, if the notches about two medians do not overlap in this display, the medians are, roughly, significantly different at about a 95% confidence level". Please, note, how emphatically the authors highlight that this is a *rough approximation*. With respect to notches, they write "Many methods, both classical and non- parametric, might be considered. None will likely be best in all cases." In this case it is worthwhile also looking at the help for R's `boxplot.stats()` function, where one finds the origin of the 1.58 described as "[The notches] are based on asymptotic normality of the median and roughly equal sample sizes for the two medians being compared, and are said to be rather insensitive to the underlying distributions of the samples. The idea appears to be to give roughly a 95% confidence interval for the difference in two medians." With *roughly* once again being mentioned. We must remember that boxplots were developed as a tool for exploratory data analysis (EDA).

In this context it is good to keep in mind, that the minimum number of observations per boxplot plotted that is needed for it to be informative is considered to be between 10 and 15. In particular, in my own opinion the highlighting of outliers is most useful in EDA. When the number of observations is small, forcing the whiskers to represent the whole range of the data can result in an easier to interpret plot.